# Eclipse: after build no such file or directory

Tags: c, eclipse, build, makefile

I have done the following:

1. Added the path to my include folder under Paths and Symbols->includes tab
2. The header file now appear in my project folder under includes
3. The #include files no longer give errors as the project can see the .h files that it needs
4. After build I get the following error:

   fatal error: services.h: No such file or directory
   make:***[filename]Error 1

My .c source file now complains that it cant see the include file. How do I fix this?

Comment: What is your build command?  It looks like the -I is not being updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Eclipse import a new make file project. Then link the appropriate libraries.